# Scala pass function as argument and execute conditionally

Tags: scala

Say  I have an object with a method called `protect`.

This is supposed to take a function with `JValue => JValue`(non generic parameters).

```
 def protect(func: (JValue) => JValue) = {
        if (Something.is) {
            InMemoryResponse(Array(), Nil, Nil, 200)
        } else {
            InMemoryResponse(Array(), Nil, Nil, 401)
        }
  }
```

How can I now call the function passing its original argument?

The goal is to check if a user session exists before responding to a REST request. If it doesn't then a `401 Forbidden` will be returned automatically, so something like the following. In this case I want to pass `Users.getUsers` as the argument function and limit as the param to the function.

So inside `protect`, if the `Session` exists the function will execute and display.

```
serve {
    case "user" :: limit :: Nil JsonGet _ =>
        AuthorizedReq.protect(json => Users.getUsers(limit))
```

Comment: Please, don't use pattern matching for true/false :-( simple `if` should be enough

Comment: `if (Something.is) trueCaseResult else falseCaseResult`. Additionally, don't put braces around `case` expressions. In general avoid superfluous punctuation—it's usually just noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using this:

```
object AuthorizedReq extends Logger {
    private[this] val error: JValue = ("error" -> "Unauthorized request");
    def protect(func: (JValue) => JValue, json: JValue): JValue = {
        if (LoginSession.is) {
                new OkResponse
                func(json)
            } else {
                new UnauthorizedResponse
                error;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In combination with:

```
serve {
    case "user" :: limit :: Nil JsonPost json -> _ =>
        for {
            json <- AuthorizedReq.protect(json => Users.getUsers(json), json)
        } yield json: JValue
}
```

If the user is not authenticated, server responds with `401`, otherwise the original function executes. It should be easy enough to introduce roles and realms.

This replaces Lift's default auth mechanism, which lacks documentation.

Comment: Don't use `return`. (No exceptions until you're well beyond the novice Scala programmer stage.)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you're *not* actually passing the function `Users.getUsers` as a parameter. You're passing a function which *calls* this function, using the `limit` parameter.

Because when you create the anonymous function that you're passing as a parameter you also create a closure, the value of `limit` is still available to the function (although not visible to you). You should be able to just call `func` with no arguments and have it work fine.